# Jest testing on firebase emulators can't find database URL?

Tags: firebase, jestjs, firebase-cli

I'm trying to run Jest unit tests on the firebase emulators with:

```
firebase emulators:exec 'jest'
```

I'm including `firebase-admin` and `initializeApp` in the test file:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

it("tests", async () => {
  admin.database().ref('foo').set("bar");
  ...
```

but I get the error:

> Can't determine Firebase Database URL.

Doesn't running `'jest'` through `firebase emulators:exec` automatically set up the firebase project to point to the emulators? Is there some other configuration that I'm missing?

I've set up an example git repo here that demonstrates this issue.

https://github.com/nicholasstephan/firebase-emulator-test

Comment: I suggest posting an issue on the firebase-tools GitHub if you're having problems working with the Firebase emulator suite.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: And I don't think there is anything special delivered to the script with emulator:exec.  You probably still have to configure your program to look at the emulator.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_and_prototype

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson. I'm hesitant to submit a bug report to firebase-tools as I'm not entirely sure I'm doing it correctly. Have you executed test scripts on the firebase emulators? Am I missing something? I've pulled the relevant bits into a git repo to show what I'm trying to do.

Comment: As I said, I think you still probably have to configure your script to connection to the emulator using the information in the link I provided.  Have you done that?

Answer (score 3):

In order to run jest unit tests with `firebase emulators:exec` a database url must be specified (by providing a service account) or by setting `FIREBASE_DATABASE_EMULATOR_HOST`. In order to run the default emulator, set `FIREBASE_DATABASE_EMULATOR_HOST="localhost:9000"` before running `firebase emulators:exec`. To look at the data being written to the database go to; `http://localhost:9000/path/to/data.json?ns=not-a-project`. If a service account is provided the namespace of the project (ns) is instead the namespace of the project.